# Get contents of shared Google Drive Spreadsheet file via PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

My application has support for importing data from Excel document. I want to add support for importing data from Google Drive Spreadsheet by just copy pasting link (instead of saving it and selecting from downloads folder).

This code works fine for publicly available files (via sharing link):

```
$url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=...&exportFormat=xlsx';
file_put_contents('path/to/file.xlsx', file_get_contents($url));
```

Then I pass save file path to importer and it works.

For private files this code doesn't make sense because we get permission error and HTML is retrieved instead of Excel data.

I installed the latest version of [google/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), followed the steps described in [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) article.

My `oauth2callback.php` file contents:

```
<?php

require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client;
$client->setAuthConfigFile('/path/to/google_auth_config.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirectUri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectUri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

The main code looks like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client;
$client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/google_auth_config.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);    
    $fileId = '...';
    // For testing purposes
    $file = $driveService->files->get($fileId);
    $content = $driveService->files->get($fileId, ['alt' => 'media']);   
    $content = $driveService->files->export(
        $fileId,
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        ['alt' => 'media']
    );       
} else {
    $redirectUri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectUri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

This:

```
$file = $driveService->files->get($fileId);
```

works fine, I get valid `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` instance.

Downloading examples were taken from [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) documentation.

This:

```
$content = $driveService->files->get($fileId, ['alt' => 'media']);
```

throws an exception:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest",
                "message": "The specified file does not support the requested alternate representation.",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": "alt"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The specified file does not support the requested alternate representation."
    }
}
```

This:

```
$content = $driveService->files->export(
    $fileId,
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    ['alt' => 'media']
);
```

gives an error:

> Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource::export()

User has editor permission to this shared folder, `downloadUrl` and `exportLinks` properties are `null` in `$file`, but I can get properties like `title`.

Any ideas?

I saw some other examples with `Google_Http_Request` but this was replaced with Guzzle so it's useless now.

Answer (score 2):

> The specified file does not support the requested alternate representation.

There seems to be [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228698/not-able-to-download-google-spreadsheet-by-google-drive-api-using-python) regarding the issue. Basically it indicates that Sheets don't have media. You can try to remove the `alt=media` parameter when getting the Sheets file.

> Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource::export()

The `export` method is undefined in the namespace. Check if you're using the `v1-branch` of the php client repo as indicated on the link you cited. The [v1-branch Service.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php) seems to have the export method so it may work; wereas the [master Drive.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php) doesn't have one (which causes the error)